# SQL query to get / delimited column value in single row

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have this output:

Table 1

| Requisition_number | per_id | per_name | Job_title | Interview | TAS_EMAIL_ADDRESS | TAS_FNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22021 | 1097 | Chad | Manager | This is a comment | abc.g@gmail.COM | abc |
| 22021 | 1097 | Chad | Manager | This is a comment | xyz.g@gmail.COM | xyz |

I want the output to look like this:

| Requisition_number | per_id | per_name | Job_title | Interview | TAS_EMAIL_ADDRESS | TAS_FNAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22021 | 1097 | Chad | Manager | This is a comment | abc.g@gmail.COM | abc/xyz |
| 22021 | 1097 | Chad | Manager | This is a comment | xyz.g@gmail.COM |  |

i.e for the same `requistion_number` for the same `per_id`, if all other columns are same except the `TAS_EMAIL_ADDRESS`, I want to concatenate the

```
TAS_FNAME - abc/xyz
```

and repeat in the rows.

I am using this expression in my query:

```
rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement(e,tas_fname||'/')).extract ('//text()'), '/') AS tas_fname
```

but this is not working and giving the same output like table 1.

listagg function is throwing a syntax error when I am using it with within group (order by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LISTAGG` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT Requisition_number,
       per_id,
       per_name,
       Job_title,
       Interview,
       TAS_EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
       CASE ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (
              PARTITION BY Requisition_number,
                           per_id,
                           per_name,
                           Job_title,
                           Interview
              ORDER     BY tas_fname
            )
       WHEN 1
       THEN LISTAGG(tas_fname, '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY tas_fname)
            OVER (
              PARTITION BY Requisition_number,
                           per_id,
                           per_name,
                           Job_title,
                           Interview
            )
       END AS tas_fname
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample dataL

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Requisition_number, per_id, per_name, Job_title, Interview, TAS_EMAIL_ADDRESS, TAS_FNAME) AS
SELECT 22021, 1097, 'Chad', 'Manager', 'This is a comment', 'abc.g@gmail.COM', 'abc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 22021, 1097, 'Chad', 'Manager', 'This is a comment', 'xyz.g@gmail.COM', 'xyz' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | REQUISITION_NUMBER | PER_ID | PER_NAME | JOB_TITLE | INTERVIEW | TAS_EMAIL_ADDRESS | TAS_FNAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 22021 | 1097 | Chad | Manager | This is a comment | abc.g@gmail.COM | abc/xyz |
> | 22021 | 1097 | Chad | Manager | This is a comment | xyz.g@gmail.COM | *null* |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=098b789c691e24e3176789acfa1879dc)*

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code good day.

```
Drop table Address
Create Table Address (
ID int NOT NULL,
email Varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO Address (ID,email) VALUES (1, 'abc.g@gmail.com') 
INSERT INTO Address (ID,email) VALUES (1, 'xyz.g@gmail.com')   
INSERT INTO Address (ID,email) VALUES (2, 'qqq.g@gmail.com') 
INSERT INTO Address (ID,email) VALUES (2, 'bbb.g@gmail.com') 
INSERT INTO Address (ID,email) VALUES (3, 'aaa.g@gmail.com') 
INSERT INTO Address (ID,email) VALUES (3, 'ccc.g@gmail.com')
INSERT INTO Address (ID,email) VALUES (3, 'ddd.g@gmail.com') 
Select
ID,LISTAGG(Regexp_replace(email,'[.].+'), '/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) 
"Result"
From Address
Group By ID
```